# Кодировка в ZeosLib 7.1.3a

Tags: delphi, кодировка, база-данных

Изначально программа была сделана с компонентами ZeosLib 7.0.1-beta в Delphi. Обновил до версии ZeosLib 7.1.3a. Появилась проблема с кодировкой в базе, которая была создана с ZeosLib 7.0.1-beta, - русские буквы отображаются нечитабельно. Использую utf-8. Как можно **в старой** БД решить данную проблему?

Comment: плиз, подскажите!!!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте после подключения к базе выполнить 2 запроса:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET @@collation_connection = @@collation_database;
```